# javascript unexpected calculation result

Tags: javascript

Codes:

```
g = function () {
  H = 3
  return H + H
}

f = function () {
  Η = 2
  return Η + H
}

// 3 + 3 = 6
alert(g())
// 2 + 2 = 5
alert(f())
```

Live demo:http://jsfiddle.net/qhRJY/light/

While the output is `6` and `5`.

It is strange.

Then I try to change the value of the `H`, the result is still unexpected.

What's the magic here?

Comment: Given the actual answer, this seems like kind of time wasting trick question.

Comment: [Hey, look on the bright side](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5)

Comment: Since it seems you copied [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28862), why didn't you just read the explanation?

Comment: I did not copy the answer you mentioned.

Comment: Once more, I am even not sure if this a problem of the javascript or something else. I changed the value, but still got the unexpected result. Which made me can not know how to search it. Even I say a damn after I read the answer by "Barmar" but it is really a STRANGE problem for me.

Comment: Are we really supposed to believe that you came up with this by yourself, and didn't realize that you typed H and Eta, instead of copying the functions from that other answer? It's exactly the same, I don't believe you didn't copy it.

Comment: Of course, I copy the codes but not from any existed answer like "Felix Kling" post. I would not ask a solved problem, it make no sense. I get the codes from another forum, and found it is strange when I run it in the console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `f`, the first and second `Η` are actually the Greek letter `Eta`, not the Roman `H`. They look similar, but they're not the same character. It has Unicode code point 0x51377, rather than ASCII code 0x48. So you're adding two different variables.

Would you find the answer unexpected if it were written like this? Because this is equivalent to what you wrote.

```
g = function () {
  H = 3
  return H + H
}

f = function () {
  Eta = 2
  return Eta + H
}

// 3 + 3 = 6
alert(g())
// 2 + 2 = 5
alert(f())
```

Comment: This is absolutely the answer.

Comment: Man I had a feeling it was something like this. One of the H was black in jsfiddle's syntax highlighter while the others were blue.

Comment: Yep, when I type in H, instead of the character in jsfiddle I get 6 and 6. Is this a trick question..lol

Comment: JSFiddle is can act weird when copy / paste into text editors. be careful.

Comment: I never noticed the slight difference between the `H`. Since I never thought it would be a trick here. I spend all the time on the scope of the variable `H`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a tricky question .Modify the problem with alphabet H.It seems like Roman letters or something special characters.It works fine with 'H' for me.

Comment: @BalajiKandasamy please review the edited answer

Answer (score -4):

```
f = function () {
  Η = 3
  return Η + H
}
```

for this code, change to this

```
f = function () {
  I = 3;
  return I + I;
}
```

The 'H' is not cleared from the first function, it's still using the previous value. 2 + 3 = 5

Comment: Yeah, but WHY?  He's setting `H = 3` BEFORE return `H + H`.  You haven't explained why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: wow, I'm trying to help and why so many down votes?...

Comment: Probably because what you wrote doesn't explain why the code behaves like it does.